# Unknown AID UICC initialization iPhone SE2

Tags: apdu, sim-card

When inserting an UICC in an iPhone SE2 and recording the APDU messages between the modem and the UICC I see a sequence opening a logical channel and trying to select an application. I could not find any reference to this application. What is it?

```
01 a4 04 0c 10 a0 00 00 00 09 02 03 ff ff ff ff 89 01 00 00 ff
```

The RID `a0 00 00 00 09` is registered for the ETSI.

Comment: I think it's information encoded in accordance with ETSI TS 101 220, part 4 "Structure of the Application IDentifier (AID)"  https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/101200_101299/101220/13.00.00_60/ts_101220v130000p.pdf

Comment: Yes, I know. But what is this application doing and who provides it?